# Entity Framework DbUpdateException when storing m:n relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having troubles with creating and/or storing m:n relationship with EF 4.3 Code first

So the first entity `Publication` is defined as with some other internal scalar properties:

```
    public class Publication : IDataErrorInfo{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Publications")]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

and the other class in the same way:

```
    public class Group : IDataErrorInfo {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Groups")]
    public ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
```

which according to numerous articles should be fine.

There are several problems I occur. AT first:

- If I create a new publication and assert it some Groups. All is stored to the db. But then I restart the program, the same particular publication has ICollection set to null. Therefore the information about relationship with Group has been deleted.I don't know why :(
- When I try to update exisiting Publication entry with Group relationship, the DBUpdateException is thrown with the following text:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types

In the inner exception is the same, and in the inner exception of this one is the following:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*Publicat*_3AF5D6A10AD2A005'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PublicationGroups'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I'm asserting the the new values of the Publication as follows:

```
var entry = db.Publications.First(a => a.PublicationId == publKey);
entry.Groups = db.Groups.
                Where(a => groupKeys.Contains(a.GroupId)).
                Select(b => b).
                ToList();
```

where `publKey` is the key of the edited entity and `groupKeys` is the List of GroupId which should be the publication be related to.

after calling `db.SaveContext()` the exception is thrown

This topic has been covered by numerous articles, but I didn't find any solution. All of the examples are using the same code, but apparently I'm missing something. I'm using SQL Ce 4.0 as the persistance data storage.

Thank you guys for answer, I'm dealing with it since yesterday, but don't why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling .Save after you've added the groups to the database?  Otherwise when you try to add the groups to the publication, they won't actually be in the DbSet yet.  The following code works for me - perhaps you could clarify how it differs from yours?

```
public class Publication
{
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }
    public string PublicationName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());

        Context context = new Context();

        // Only add the groups if it's a new database
        if (!context.Groups.Any())
        {
            context.Groups.Add(new Group { GroupName = "Group 1" });
            context.Groups.Add(new Group { GroupName = "Group 2" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (context.Publications.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("At startup, P1 is in groups " + String.Join(", ", context.Publications.First().Groups.Select(g => g.GroupName)));
        }

        // Add publication
        Publication p;
        p = new Publication();
        p.Groups = context.Groups.ToList();     // Add to all existing groups
        context.Publications.Add(p);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("P1 is in groups " + String.Join(", ", context.Publications.First().Groups.Select(g => g.GroupName)));
    }
}
```

(Code Updated to use SqlCe provider)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, basically it is all the same except for Initializer, which is DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges and Ids anotations which are [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)], which db provider do you use? The groups are already stored in db. so can be gained like Group g = db.Groups.First() and set like publication.Groups = new List<Group>{group}. In case publication is not in db, all is saved, but after restart publication.Groups = null???? and in case publication already exists in db, the exception is thrown. So I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Your Key and DatabaseGenerate attributes are redundant, since they get picked anyway.  The initializer is just one I normally use for samples - it isn't required!  Could you try posting a full sample (or modifying mine) to make it fail in the same way as yours?

Comment: well I have commented the [Key] and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and so far it looks as the problem has been solved.. or at leas it throwns a different exception :) - DbEntityValidation error with no other information but,  System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult - so I need to figure out this. but it's definetely a progress :)

Comment: I had to add an additional text property to my classes when converting to SqlCe, as SqlCe wouldn't add a row with only an identity column.  I've stripped it down to the bare minimum and it still works.

Comment: have you tried to start the program without the dropping the db? Don't know why, but I still get the same error. The validation exception was my fault. I'll try your example

Comment: I've run the program successfully without dropping the DB, this still runs fine.  The publication is still part of both groups on the second start.